# Which approach is better creating database programmatically or copying it from assets folder?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Since there are two ways by which we can store or copy the data from database. one is from sqlite file which we lay in assets folder and another by database which is created programmatically.

I have following questions regarding the sqlite database in android:

1.which performs faster while getting performing select query from database and why?

2.what are the advantages of each approach.

I found on internet but i could not get any proper information, the only thing that i come to know by Googling is copying data from assets is better for static data like list of country(that is obvious because you will not perform any bulk operation of inserting data programmatcially in android). Any help regarding this is appreciated . :)

Comment: Copying a database from assets may be faster for setting up the initial database, instead of executing SQL statements at time time of creating the database. Once created, though, the database will behave the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not make a difference.

Your select query is performed on the final database, which would be identical whether you copied it from assets, or imported it programmatically. Your approach to its creation does not influence its behaviour.

As for advantages, that's entirely up to you. In some scenarios, having a base database in assets would give you better, and easier to read, control over versioning, as you could commit it easily with your repository, vs. having thousands of SQL statements in code.

On the flip side, updating a database that you copy from the assets folder with each version could be difficult, especially if you modify data within the app frequently. Instead of programmatically simply altering the schema or data on update, you would have to export any modifications, copy the new database, and then import all your modifications by performing some form of merge.

Comment: oh.ok. thnx for the instant reply. I was just curious about this question. thnx for help :)